# select element by selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to select an element from the following html code:

```
<ul class="selectReplace opened">
<li class="default">Standardpizzor</li>
<li class="first">Standardpizzor</li>
<li class="">Specialpizzor</li>
<li class="">Kebab</li>
<li class="last">Dricker</li>
</ul>
```

by Selenium RC command:

```
selenium.click("//ul/li[4]");
```

but no luck! Please help me out if anybody have any solution.

Comment: What happens when this code runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the text 'Dricker' to be selected.  You can use the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680782).

```
selenium.runScript("
    function selectElementContents(el,start,end) { 
        var sel = window.getSelection(); 
        var range = window.document.createRange();     
        range.setStart(el,start); range.setEnd(el,end); 
        sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range); 
    }     
    selectElementContents(window.document.getElementsByTagName("li")[4].firstChild,0,7);
");
```