# Selecting parts of div text via the code

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to select specific text inside a div using the code. I have a div of text, and I need to iterate through each word selecting it individually, then deslecting and onto the next word.

I'm not talking about simulating a select by changing the background css of the words requiring highlighting, but actually selecting it so the outcome is the same as if the user used the mouse to select it.

I know it's possible inside a text area input, but is it possible on a Div?

------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------

Ok this is where I'm at with it after having another look at it today.  I can select all the text in a span, but not specifically a range of words within that span.  The closest I have come ( code shown below...  ) is selecting the range manually, then removing the selection, then reapplying it.

```
<div contentEditable = 'true' id="theDiv">
A selection of words but only from here to here to be selected
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval( function() {
    var currSelection = window.getSelection();
    var storedSelections = [];

    if ( currSelection ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currSelection.rangeCount; i++) {
            storedSelections.push (currSelection.getRangeAt (i));
        }
        currSelection.removeAllRanges ();
    }

    if ( storedSelections.length != 0 ) {
        currSelection.addRange( storedSelections[0] )
    } 
}, 1000 );
</script>
```

The stored selection range object has a startOffset and endOffset property.  My question is how do I set this alongside the initial selection via the code ( not via a mouse select ) ?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Provide a little bit more info about what you want the outcome to be.

Comment: It's definitely possible because HTML editors us DIVs in combination with 'contenteditable' to achieve things that relate to what you're trying to do (assumption here).

Comment: What browsers do you care about? The Selections API allows this but it's not supported by IE (Edge will have it)

Comment: Yes I looked into contenteditable in the hope it would allow the div to function like a text area but it didn't unfortunately.

Comment: Would need to be just chrome compatible

Comment: Apparently document.execCommand('copy') is supported by most current browsers. Scroll down to the answer with 70 upvotes for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't shed any light on how to select specific words in a div.

Comment: Sorry, select a specific block of words I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article, it's difficult to summarise, so better read it:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

This answer here can be useful too:

[Can you set and/or change the user’s text selection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183401/can-you-set-and-or-change-the-user-s-text-selection-in-javascript)

Comment: As much as I like PPK, that Quirksmode article appears to be very old; I'm not sure of how much use it still is today.

Comment: Well, I think at least he'll get some ideas on how this works and what should he look further

Comment: Unfortunately the quirksmode didn't provide an answer.  The method it suggested to set a range of text didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's fairly straightforward...

```
<div id = "theDiv">adsf asdf asdf asdf</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var theDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv')
    theDivFirstChild = theDiv.firstChild;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart( theDivFirstChild, 2 );
    range.setEnd( theDivFirstChild, 8);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
</script>
```