# jquery select image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to copy an image to the clipboard. Given it is not allowed to copy image due to security reason, the use case I want to tackle is:

1. the user presses copy button
2. through jquery select the image (focus and select)
3. prompt the user to press `ctrl + c` to copy the image

The problem is that if I do this for an input, I can easily select the text inside that, but I am not able to do it for an image. Below is the abstracted version of what I am trying to do, mainly just select the image for now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myImage").focus();
    $("#myImage").select();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <img id="myImage" width="220" height="277" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="The Scream">
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the same example but for an input and it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myInput").focus();
    $("#myInput").select();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<input id="myInput" value="hello"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If somebody can give me the correct of way doing this it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Image elements don’t have a `select` method. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183401/can-you-set-and-or-change-the-user-s-text-selection-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) to solve my problem and found a way to copy an image to clipboard with just a button. The following was my solution.

**note it will not work until you download the cliboardjs.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="clipboard.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="myDiv">

    <img width="220" height="277" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="The Scream">

  </div>
  <button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#myDiv">
    Copy to clipboard
  </button>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      e.clearSelection();
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myImage").bind('load', function(){
        $("#myImage").focus();
        $("#myImage").select();
        alert("ok");
    });
});
```

And you should also check this: [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)