# javascript what does range.endOffset() give you?

Tags: javascript, range

When I go:

```
range.selectNodeContents(element);
```

My understanding is that the range object selects all the contents of element.  So that would mean that if I said:

```
range.startOffset();
```

I should get 0.  Which is true when testing.
But then if I say:

```
range.endOffset();
```

I would think that I get the length of the contents of the element.  But I don't.  I get 1, or 3... or numbers I don't understand.

So... what does range.endOffset()  really tell you?

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`selectNodeContents`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-selectnodecontents),

> 2. Let *length* be the [length](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-length) of *node*.
>
> 4. Set [end](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-range-end) to the [boundary point](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-range-bp) (*node*, *length*).

So the end offset is set to the [length of the node](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-length):

> To determine the **length** of a [node](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node) *node*, switch on *node*:
>
> - [DocumentType](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#documenttype)
>     Zero.
> - [Text](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#text), [ProcessingInstruction](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#processinginstruction), [Comment](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#comment)
>     The number of [code units](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-code-unit) in its [data](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-cd-data).
> - Any other node
>     Its number of [children](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-child).

That's what you will get you you call [`endOffset`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-endoffset).

Answer (score 0):

> The Range.endOffset read-only property returns a number representing
>   where in the Range.endContainer the Range ends.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endOffset