# Prevent Clearance of Selection

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, selection

```html
<p>Select Some of This Text</p>
<span>Now click this</span>
```

Is it possible to make it so that when you click on the `<span>` it doesn't remove the selection of the `<p>` or stores it somewhere? Maybe using the `onblur` event?

Comment: What is your use case for doing that? Also, can you please clarify what does it mean when you say "stores it somewhere"?

Comment: @Nishant I think “stores it somewhere” is referring to the possible solution of saving the bounds of the text selection before the browser clears it, then re-selecting that range immediately after the browser does its own setting of the selection. This could be done using whatever the equivalent of [`inputElement.setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) is for non-`input` elements. (That equivalent is `Range` – see [Can you set and/or change the user’s text selection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4183401/578288).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to prevent the selection of text within the “Now click this” button, using the CSS explained in [How to disable text selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/578288). With this CSS, clicks on the button won’t change the selection, including if there is an existing selection.

```css
.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Select Some of This Text</p>
<span class="unselectable">Now click this</span>
```