# Unable to add 2nd selection range (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, selection

I am attempting to programatically add multiple selection regions in Chrome.

From here: [Can you set and/or change the user’s text selection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183401/can-you-set-and-or-change-the-user-s-text-selection-in-javascript)

I found this function for selecting an elements text on SO (I added the clearFirst parameter):

```
function selectElementContents(el, clearFirst) {
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
//        console.log('here');
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        if (clearFirst) sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

and then tried calling it like this:

```
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
       let cell = row.insertCell();
       cell.innerText = "" + i + "," + j;
    }
  }
  $(table).on("click", function() {
    let tds = $(this).find("td");
    console.log("td: " + tds.get(0));
    selectElementContents(tds.get(0), true);
    selectElementContents(tds.get(3), false);

  });
```

The selection of the first TD works fine, but the second range is not selected. I confirmed that `selectElementContents` is going through the "true" code (where the commented out console.log is). Is adding multiple selection ranges in Chrome disallowed, or am I just not doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be contained in a Chrome extension: "Multiline Text Selection" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiline-text-selection/ajbomhojbckleofgngogoecoaefclnol?hl=en

So in default chrome, multiple selection ranges isn't supported. But this extension can enable it.